# Why is the Gaussian so pervasive in mathematics?

Tags: gm.general-mathematics, pr.probability

This is a heuristic question that I think was once asked by Serge Lang. The gaussian: $e^{-x^2}$ appears as the fixed point to the Fourier transform, in the punchline to the central limit theorem, as the solution to the heat equation, in a very nice proof of the Atiyah-Singer index theorem etc. Is this an artifact of the techniques (such as the Fourier Transform) that people like use to deal with certain problems or is this the tip of some deeper platonic iceberg?

Comment: I think the appearances you mention can be sensibly grouped in two broad classes: Fourier-analytic (including the CLT, see e.g. http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/01/05/254a-notes-2-the-central-limit-theorem/) and heat-kernelish (incl. Atiyah-Singer). Perhaps microlocal analysis is the best bridge between these.

Comment: I guess, the gaussian is as "natural" as euclidean spaces---this remark is in light of the bijections between divergences and exponential families as discussed in: ideal.ece.utexas.edu/pdfs/126.pdf (see Section 3); I would, however, love to learn of deeper connections.

Comment: I just want to point out that the appearance of the Gaussian in Atiyah-Singer isn't so mysterious.  In the McKean-Singer formula - $Index(D) = Tr_s (e^{-tD^2})$ - the Gaussian can be replaced with any smooth function which rapidly decays at infinity.  The Gaussian is used because $e^{-tD^2}$ is the solution operator for a very well understood differential equation, namely the heat equation, and thus we can look up the relevant asymptotic analysis in old PDE textbooks.

Comment: There is a book "The Normal Distribution: Characterizations with Applications" by Bryc which could be taken as a large collection of probabilistic examples to add to your list.  One of my favorites: the normal distribution in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is the unique (up to scaling) rotation-invariant probability measure with independent components.

Comment: The central limit theorem and the heat equation make no mention of the gaussian in their basic setups; it turns out to be the answer to very natural questions.  So I think those two (on the surface completely unrelated) examples show that this phenomenon is definitely not just an artifact of techniques.  In particular, there are other methods of proving the CLT or solving the heat equation besides Fourier transforms. 

Comment: Another place the Gaussian shows up is in the quantum harmonic oscillator (i.e. the eigenfunctions are the product of Hermite polynomials times the Gaussian).



Comment: Thanks for all the comments and nice examples. Another one of my very favorite uses of the Gaussian is to find the volume of the n-sphere http://planetmath.org/?op=getobj&from=objects&name=AreaOfTheNSphere but its appearance here seems to have more to do with the calculation got "factored" than some especially deep fact about spheres.

Is there some obvious relation between the CLT and the heat equation? (I know that the Fourier transform gives 2 matching ODEs in those two scenarios, but is there some less heavy handed explanation?)

Comment: The factoring that appears in that volume calculation happens precisely because the standard normal distribution has independent components; the reason you can relate the normal distribution to the sphere is its rotation invariance.  So that use of the Gaussian is an application of my favorite property which I mentioned above.  As for the CLT and the heat equation, there certainly are deep relationships, but I don't know about "obvious" or "less heavy handed".

Comment: Makes sense, thanks for that explantation about spheres. A thought: there seems to be some similarity between the formulation of the heat equation as the limit of squares with heat flow through its edges proportional to the difference of temperature and the dropping balls through pegs by relating balls to heat flow. Maybe instead of thinking of the ball as going one way or another when meeting a peg, we can consider its expectation of going either way which would be closer to the heat flow model.

Comment: @RBega: It's true that when the position and momentum observables are represented by the operators f(x) -> xf(x) and f(x) -> -ihf'(x) acting on L^2(R), the Gaussian shows up in the energy eigenvectors of the QHO. However, this rep isn't special! Pick some other separable Hilbert space of functions---for example, one of the "weighted Bergman spaces" defined in Sec. 3 of "Holomorphic Methods in Analysis & Mathematical Physics," by Hall---and unitary equivalence gives you a rep of the position and momentum operators on this space. In general, the QHO energy eigenvectors won't involve Gaussians.

Comment: Do we really want to use the word "pervasive"?  Dictionaries often struggle to find examples of it being used in a positive light.  The answers seem to indicate that the Gaussian is not all over mathematics, but contained to some fairly specific types of mathematics.

Comment: Simple diffusion models ...

Comment: To "The gaussian appears as the fixed point to the Fourier transform" : This is nothing special, the eigenspaces of the fourier transform have infinte degeneracy.

Comment: Probably answers to this question could be the content of a long book.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Quadratic (or bilinear) forms appear naturally throughout mathematics, for instance via inner product structures, or via dualisation of a linear transformation, or via Taylor expansion around the linearisation of a nonlinear operator.  The Laplace-Beltrami operator and similar second-order operators can be viewed as differential quadratic forms, for instance.

A Gaussian is basically the multiplicative or exponentiated version of a quadratic form, so it is quite natural that it comes up in multiplicative contexts, especially on spaces (such as Euclidean space) in which a natural bilinear or quadratic structure is already present.

Perhaps the one minor miracle, though, is that the Fourier transform of a Gaussian is again a Gaussian, although once one realises that the Fourier kernel is also an exponentiated bilinear form, this is not so surprising.  But it does amplify the previous paragraph: thanks to Fourier duality, Gaussians not only come up in the context of spatial multiplication, but also frequency multiplication (e.g. convolutions, and hence CLT, or heat kernels).

One can also take an adelic viewpoint.  When studying non-archimedean fields such as the p-adics $Q_p$, compact subgroups such as $Z_p$ play a pivotal role.  On the reals, it seems the natural analogue of these compact subgroups are the Gaussians (cf. Tate's thesis).  One can sort of justify the existence and central role of Gaussians on the grounds that the real number system "needs" something like the compact subgroups that its non-archimedean siblings enjoy, though this doesn't fully explain why Gaussians would then be exponentiated quadratic in nature.

Comment: How exactly do you see a Gaussian as a subgroup of $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: When you convolve Haar probability measure on a (compact) subgroup with itself, you get back the same measure, and this can in fact be used as a definition of such subgroups.  If you convolve a Gaussian probability measure with itself, you _almost_ get back the same Gaussian measure, but it has spread out by a factor of $\sqrt{2}$.  So Gaussians are in some sense a "$\sqrt{2}$-approximate group".

Answer (score 20):

(The sort of obvious answer from teaching statistics several times:)

*The sum of two independent normal random variables is again normal*, i.e., the shape of the distribution is unchanged under addition except for stretching and scaling.

Moreover, the normal distribution is unique among distributions with finite variance in having this property.

Many phenomena in nature come from adding together various independent or almost independent terms. Therefore, we would expect the normal distribution to show up a lot in nature-inspired mathematics.

Comment: The normal distribution is not unique in this property.  The same is true of all stable distributions.

Comment: @Mark: Thanks, I have added the assumption of finite variance.

Comment: Fat thumb error on the downvote. Sorry.

Comment: @TomCopeland no worries, I improved my answer now :)

Answer (score 13):

This is just a minor amplification of one of Terry Tao's points.  For any prime $p$, the ring $\mathbb{Z}_p$ of [$p$-adic integers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_number) forms an open compact additive subgroup of $\mathbb{Q}_p$, the completion of $\mathbb{Q}$ under the p-adic metric, and its characteristic function should be viewed as a p-adic analogue of the Gaussian.  It displays many analogues of the nice properties we see from the Gaussian:

1. It is smooth (in the sense that the smooth functions on totally disconnected spaces are defined as the locally constant functions, but this isn't completely tautological, since this class of functions turns out to be useful).
2. It is taken to itself under the $p$-adic Fourier transform when normalizations are chosen appropriately.
3. It obeys something like a central limit theorem.  For example, if you flip lots of coins, and ask for the number of heads mod $p^n$, you will, for sufficiently long trials, get a distribution that is close to uniform.  It sounds like there could be a way to interpret this sort of convolution in terms of heat flowing, but I don't know a precise statement.

The situation with the real line is more complicated because it is connected but not compact, and therefore has no open compact subgroups.  There is a maximal compact multiplicative monoid (occasionally called the "ring of integers of $\mathbb{R}$" informally), given by the closed interval $[-1,1]$.  You can think of the Gaussian as a smoothing of the uniform distribution on $[-1,1]$, but it is not clear to me that this particular analogy is very fruitful.

Comment: Do you know if eigenvectors of the Fourier transform (Hermite functions mentioned by Tom's new answer, over $\mathbb{R}$) are written up somewhere, in the $\mathbb{Q}_p$ case?

Comment: BTW I asked a related question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/382952/what-makes-gaussian-distributions-special-local-field-version

Answer (score 13):

One of the reasons for the ubiquity of the Gaussian is displayed in what is probably the most electrifying half page of scientific prose ever written---Maxwell's argument that the distribution of the velocities of molecules in the ideal gas is Gaussian (now known as the Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution).    The only physical assumptions used are that the density function depends only on the absolute value of the velocity (and not the direction) and that the components in the directions of the coordinate axes are statistically independent.  Mathematically, ths means that the only functions in $3$-space which depend  only on the distance $r$ from the origin and which split as the product of three functions of one variable are those of the form  $ae^{br^2}$.  Maxwell does this by inspection but it is easy to give a rigorous proof (under very weak smoothness conditions) and the result holds, of course, in any dimension greater then or equal to $2$. Maxwell's reasoning can be found in his collected papers, or, more accesssibly, in Hawking's anthology "On the Shoulders of Giants".

Comment: And this is yet another manifestation of the property I mentioned in the comments on the OP...

Comment: And of course the kinetic energy of a mass $m$ is $m \cdot v^2/2 = p^2/2m$.

Answer (score 12):

I recently came across a strange and beautiful connection between the Gaussian $e^{-x^2}$ and the method of least squares. It turns out that the square in $e^{-x^2}$ and the square in ``least squares'' is the same square.

Let $(x_i,y_i)$ (with $1\leq i \leq n$) be the data set, and assume that for each $x$, the $y$'s are normally distributed with mean $\mu(x)=\alpha x+\beta$ and variance $\sigma^2$. Then, the likelihood of generating our data (assuming that the data points are independent) is
  $$\prod_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \sigma^2}} \exp\left(-\frac{(y_i-\mu(x_i))^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)
     =\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \sigma^2}}\right)^n 
          \exp\left( \frac{-1}{2\sigma^2} \sum_{i=1}^n (y_i - \alpha x+\beta)^2 \right)$$
We would obviously want to choose the parameters $\alpha,\beta$ so that the likelihood is maximized, and this is accomplished by minimizing $$\sum_{i=1}^n (y_i - \alpha x+\beta)^2.$$ In other words, the least squares approximation is the one that makes the data set most likely to happen.

Comment: The analogous thing happens for the Laplace distribution and absolute loss, etc. There is certainly a relationship between loss criteria and distributions under which that loss minimizer is the MLE, but I'm not sure it goes any deeper. 

Comment: This is yet another manifestation of my favorite property, mentioned in the comments...

Comment: @R Hahn: See my comment below the question, (2nd from top). The relation does indeed go deeper.

Comment: @Suvrit Yeah, the geometry of the exponential family is quite natural and on the real line within this family the Gaussian is also very natural (symmetric, etc), the same way Euclidean spaces are.  But there are also lots of other interesting spaces :-)

Comment: Isn't this connection the reason why the Gaussian is called Gaussian? If I remember correctly, Gauss introduced "least squares" as a regression technique not because its derivative gives rise to a linear problem but because the square fits the "normal error model", i.e. corresponds to the Gaussian distribution.

Comment: Sorry if this is a stupid question, but you assume that the data are normally distributed so why is it surprising that the PDF for the normal distribution come up?

Comment: In a sense, there can be no surprises in math, as everything follows from the axioms! The surprise here (for me!) was that the pdf disappears from the problem, leaving just the sum of squared errors for minimization. Not a mystery, to be sure, but a pleasant surprise.

Comment: Been a long time since I worked on least squares, but orthogonality, the Pythagorean theorem, projection onto a subspace, and minimum distance to the subspace are intimately connected, and I believe the linear LSM involves finding the solution of something like $(M \cdot M^T)^{-1} v$ that gives the noise vector orthogonal to the subspace spanned by the acceptable solutions. I think Strang in "Intro. to Applied Mathematics" presents these ideas and expands on them. Any function whose minimum is then dependent on the minimum distance to the subspace of solns would then also be minimized.

Comment: I believe Laplace understood and used relations among Fourier-series fit to data, least squares fit, Gram--Schmidt orthogonalization (before G-S), probability theory and the normal (Gaussian) distribution, the CLT, and no doubt heat flow (since he conducted experiments on the specific heat of substances with Lavoisier).

Answer (score 8):

I'm not an expert, but I believe Stein's method gives a more satisfying connection between the CLT and the heat equation, in particular one that does not involve the Fourier transform.  Stein's characterization of the normal distribution and convergence to normality involves an operator closely related to the generator of the Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process.  On the other hand, the fact that latter has the Gaussian as its invariant measure can be obtained by a trivial transformation of the fundamental solution of the heat equation.

Comment: Relations among the Hermite polynomials, their raising op, and the Ornstein-Uhlenbeck operator are given in https://mathoverflow.net/questions/184978/greens-function-of-the-ornstein-uhlenbeck-operator.

Answer (score 5):

Edit 2/15/2022{

The utility of the Gaussian $e^{\frac{t^2}{2}}$--its numerous properties--derives from the nature of the coefficients of its Taylor series expansion, naturally. The coefficients, which are aerated OEIS [A001147](https://oeis.org/A001147), the odd double factorials $n!!$, enumerate the number of perfect matchings of the vertices of the n-simplices / hypertetrahedra {and complete graphs}. In "Gaussian processes and Feynman diagrams", Faris succinctly sketches the relationship between this characterization and Feynman graphs. In "Graphs on surfaces and their applications", Lando and Zvonkin go into more detail on this and present further associations. The associated Appell sequence, one family of Hermite polynomials, $He_n(z)$ with the e.g.f. $e^{\frac{t^2}{2}} e^{zt}$ has two complementary generators: the raising op $z + \partial_z$ and the binomial transform $e^\frac{{\partial_z^2}}{2} \; z^n = He_n(z)$, from which the properties of the Gaussian, important in so many applications in analysis, algebra, probability, and physics, can be easily derived. When I see a family of Hermite polynomials, I think pair matchings, ribbon graphs, Heisenberg-Weyl ladder ops, orthogonality, heat/diffusion evolution equation, normal-ordering ([A344678](https://oeis.org/A344678)), quantum physics, and the Gaussian distribution, and, conversely.

(Revamped 2/25/21)

The Heisenberg-Weyl algebra associated with the Appell polynomial calculus of the Hermite polynomials provides a way to quickly derive and collate diverse properties of the Gaussian $e^{ \frac{t^2}{\sigma}}$ and connect these to important constructs in math and physics, such as those mentioned in the other responses. The quadratic argument suggests easy extensions to higher dimensions and metrics.

**The Hermite polynomials and the Gaussian**

The Gaussian is the exponential generating function (e.g.f) for the basic moment sequence for families of Hermite polynomials. One family, $H_n(x)= (H.(x))^n$, in umbral notation, can be characterized several equivalent ways. Three are by the

***1) e.g.f.***

$$e^{H.(x)t} = e^{t^2} \; e^{xt} = e^{h.t} \; e^{xt} = e^{(h.+x)t},$$

giving

$$H_n(x) = (h.+x)^n = (H.(0)+x)^n$$

with

$$h_n = H_n(0) = |\cos(\frac{\pi n}{2})| \; \frac{n!}{(\frac{n}{2})!} ,$$

***2) binomial generating operator (BGO) and inverse*** (the heat operator in this case at unit time)

$$ e^{D^2} \; x^n = e^{h.D} \; x^n = (x+h.)^n = H_n(x)$$

with $h_n$ defined as above as the Taylor series coefficients of the Gaussian, and with the inverse

$$e^{-D^2} \; H_n(x) = x^n,$$

($D_{\omega} = \partial_{\omega} = \frac{\partial}{\partial \omega}$ can be considered a partial derivative throughout these notes with the variable often suppressed when obvious for readability),

***3) raising (creation) operator***

$$ R \; H_n(x) = H_{n+1}(x) $$

with

$$R = e^{D_x^2} \; x \; e^{-D_x^2} = x + D_{t=D_x} \; \ln[e^{t^2}] = x + 2 D_x.$$

The first equality in this last string is easily demonstrated using the action of the BGO and its inverse.

$$ R \; H_n(x) =  e^{D^2} \; x \; e^{-D^2} \; H_n(x) = e^{D^2} \; x \; x^n = e^{D^2}  \; x^{n+1} = H_{n+1}(x).$$

To relate a central concept in the Sheffer polynomial calculus, let $e^{-D^2} x^n = \hat{H}_n(x)$, the umbral compositional inverse (UCI) to the family $H_n(x)$. Then this last equation reads umbrally as

$$R \; H_n(x) =  e^{D^2} \; x \; e^{-D^2} \; H_n(x) = e^{D^2} \; x  \; H_n(\hat{H}.(x)) = e^{D^2} \; x \; x^n $$

$$ = e^{D^2}  \; x^{n+1} = H_{n+1}(x).$$

(The relation to the log can be shown via the Graves-Pincherle commutator/derivative as in [this MO-Q](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/382735/whats-the-matrix-of-logarithm-of-derivative-operator-ln-d-what-is-the-rol/383563#383563).) Note this is an operator conjugation of the basic raising op for the fundamental Appell polynomial sequence $p_n(x) = x^n$.

***4) lowering (annihilation / destruction) operator***

The lowering op for all Appell sequences is the derivative since they all have the same binomial expansion as the Hermite polynomials, just with different moments,

$$D_x \; H_n(x) = D_x \; (h.+x)^n = n \; (h.+x)^{n-1} = n \; H_{n-1}(x).$$

In fact, any polynomial sequence with $p_0(x)=1$ such that $D \; p_n(x) = n \; p_{n-1}(x)$ is an Appell sequence.

Already, we have, in 1), a form, the e.g.f., related to  the integrand for characteristic functions for the Gaussian, used in dealing with the moments and cumulants of random variables; in 2), the heat operator $e^{-D_x^2}$ and its inverse, evaluated at unit time; and, in 3) and 4), forms of the ladder ops of quantum mechanics--the ops of the Graves-Lie-Heisenberg-Weyl group/algebra.

**_____________________________________**

**A) Integral transforms of the Gaussian**

These characterizations can be used to show that the Gaussian gives a Gaussian under a Fourier transformation (FT) and a two-sided Laplace transform (LPT). The solution to the heat equation (or Cauchy problem) can be derived using the FT, and the orthogonality of Hermite polynomials derived from the LPT.

The raising op gives

$$e^{tR} \; 1 = e^{H.(x)t}= e^{t^2} \; e^{xt},$$

so

$$D_t \; e^{t^2} \; e^{xt} = D_t \; e^{tR} \; 1 = R \; e^{t^2} \; e^{xt}.$$

Changing the variable $t \to it$ gives

$$ -iD_t  \;  e^{-t^2} \; e^{ixt} = R  \; e^{-t^2} \; e^{ixt} \;,  $$

and integrating gives

$$ i \; \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \; D_t \; e^{-t^2} \; e^{ixt} \; dt = R \; \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  \; e^{-t^2} \; e^{ixt} \; dt \;, $$

so

$$ 0 = (x + 2D_x) \; FT^{-1}[e^{-t^2}].$$

But also

$$ (x + 2D_x) \; e^{-{(\frac{x}{2})}^2} = 0,$$

so the complex conjugate gives the standard Fourier transform

$$ FT[e^{-t^2}] = C \; e^{-{(\frac{x}{2})}^2},$$

where $C=\sqrt{\pi}$. (The normalization factor can be read off from the Mellin transform of the Gaussian as shown below, or it can be determined the usual way by squaring the integral with $x=0$ and converting to polar coordinates.)

Substituting $-ix$ for $x$ in the FT or $ix$ in the inverse FT gives

$$ i \; \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \; D_t \; e^{-t^2} \; e^{-xt} \; dt = i \;(x - 2D_x) \; \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  \; e^{-t^2} \; e^{-xt} \; dt ,$$

(note $\hat{R} = x - 2D_x$ is the raising op for $\hat{H}(n(x)$),

and since

$-t^2 - xt = -(t + \frac{x}{2})^2 + (\frac{x}{2})^2,$

$$0 = (x - 2D_x) \; \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  \; e^{-t^2} \; e^{-xt} \; dt .$$

Also

$$(x- 2D_x) \; e^{(\frac{x}{2})^2} =0,$$

so the two-sided LPT of the Gaussian is

$$LPT[e^{-t^2}] = \sqrt{\pi} \; e^{(\frac{x}{2})^2}.$$

Because the Gaussian is essentially self-reciprocal under the Fourier transform, the equality in the quantum mechanical uncertainty relation is achieved only for freely moving particles whose probability amplitudes are characterized as Gaussian wave packets.

**_____________________________________**

**B) The heat equation** ([Cauchy problem](https://web.iitd.ac.in/%7Evvksrini/Oldhomepage/1d-fund-heat.pdf))

Now with $t$ time and $x$ spatial displacement in this section,

$$ D_t \; f(t,x) = D_x^2 \; f(t,x)$$

is satisfied by

$$ e^{tD_x^2} \; f(0,x) = f(t,x).$$

The [Green's function](https://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/dbs26/1BMethods/GreensPDE.pdf) solution satisfies

$$ G(0^{+},x) = \delta(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{i2\pi \omega x} \; d\omega$$

and

$$G(1,x) = e^{D^2} \; \delta(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{i2\pi \omega H.(x) } \; d\omega  = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-(2\pi \omega)^2} e^{i2\pi x \omega} \; d\omega = \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{\pi}} \; e^{-(\frac{x}{2})^2}  .$$

With $x = \sqrt{t} \; u$, then

$$G(t,x) = e^{tD_x^2} \; \delta(x) = e^{D_u^2} \; \delta(\sqrt{t} \; u) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{t}} e^{D_u^2} \; \delta(u)$$

$$ = \frac{1}{ \sqrt{t}} \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{\pi}} \; e^{-(\frac{u}{2})^2} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi t}} \; e^{-\frac{x^2}{4t}} ,$$

and the general solution is the convolution

$$f(t,x) = e^{tD^2_x} \; f(0,x) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(0,u) \; G(t,u-x) \; du.$$

This integral is a Segal-Bargmann transform discussed by Cartier in "[Mathemagics](https://eudml.org/doc/122305)" and by Hall in "[Holomorphic methods in analysis and mathematical physics](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9912054)."

This is consistent with the BGO when $f(0,x) = x^n$, for which $f(1,x) = e^{D^2} \; x^n = H_n(x).$ And, that any Appell sequence/coefficient matrix can be transformed into any other Appell sequence/coefficient matrix suggests more general 'heat equations' associated to these Appell sequences can be transformed into the Hermite heat equation.

The time can be rescaled to include a diffusion constant (or adjustable variance in the probabilist's jargon).

For some of the physical import of the heat equation, see "[Random Walk and the Theory of Brownian Motion](https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/upload_library/22/Chauvenet/Kac1947.pdf)" by Mark Kac and "[Brownian motion and potential theory](https://sites.google.com/site/reubenhersharticlesetc/home/articles)" by Hersh and Griego.

**_____________________________________**

**C) The quantum harmonic oscillator**

To dovetail with Cartier's arguments, best to jump to another family of Hermite polynomials, that of the probabilists or statisticians $SH_n(x)$, with the

***1) e.g.f.***

$$ e^{SH.(x)t} = e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}} \; e^{xt} \; ,$$

***2) BGO and the inverse*** (the B-transform in Cartier)

$$ e^{-\frac{D^2}{2}} \; x^n = SH_n(x)  $$

and

$$ e^{\frac{D^2}{2}} \; SH_n(x) = x^n \; ,$$

***3) raising op***

$$R = e^{-\frac{D^2}{2}} \; x \; e^{\frac{D^2}{2}} = x - D \; .$$

Conjugations transform the between the spaces described and listed in the table on page 46 by Cartier. From the Fock $\mathfrak{F(c)}$ to $\mathfrak{L^2(d\gamma)}$ space, for the raising ops,

$$ e^{-\frac{D_z^2}{2}} \; z^n \; e^{\frac{D_z^2}{2}} = z - D_z,$$

the lowering op under this conjugation remains invariant as the derivative $D_z$, and for the bases

$$ e^{-\frac{D_z^2}{2}} \; z^n = SH_n(z).$$

From $\mathfrak{L^2(d\gamma)}$ to $\mathfrak{L^2(R)}$, for the raising and lowering ops,

$$ e^{-\frac{x^2}{4}} \; (x -D_x) \;  e^{\frac{x^2}{4}} = \frac{x}{2} - D_x,$$

$$ e^{-\frac{x^2}{4}} \; D_x \;  e^{\frac{x^2}{4}} = \frac{x}{2} + D_x,$$

and, for the bases,

$$ e^{-\frac{x^2}{4}} \; SH_n(x) = QH_n(x).$$

***The number / state / Euler op*** for a basis set $p_n(x)$ characterized by lowering, $L$, and raising, $R$, ops is $E = RL$. For example, for $p_n(x) = x^n$, the Euler op is $xD_x$ and $xD_x \; p_n(x) = n \; p_n(x)$. For $\mathfrak{L^2(R)}$ space, action of the Euler op on the basis set gives essentially the Hamiltonian for the quantum harmonic oscillator (mod scaling factors)

$$E = (\frac{x}{2} - D_x) \;(\frac{x}{2} + D_x) = -D_x^2 + \frac{x^2}{4} - \frac{1}{2} ,$$

so

$$ (-D_x^2 + \frac{x^2}{4}) \; QH_n(x) =  (n + \frac{1}{2}) \; QH_n(x).$$

**_____________________________________**

**D) The Gaussian and orthogonality of Hermite polynomials**

As noted above the sequence of Hermite polynomials $\hat{H}_n(x)$ that is the UCI to the family $H_n(x)$ has the e.g.f.

***1) e.g.f.***

$$e^{\hat{H}.(x)t} = e^{-t^2} e^{xt}$$

with

$$\hat{h}_n = \cos(\frac{\pi n}{2}) \; \frac{n!}{(\frac{n}{2})!},$$

***2) BGO and inverse***

$$e^{-D_x^2}  \; x^n = \hat{H}_n(x),$$

with inverse

$$e^{D_x^2}   \hat{H}_n(x) = \; x^n ,$$

***3) raising op***

$$\hat{R} = e^{-D^2} \; x \; e^{D^2}= x- 2 \: D_x.$$

From the e.g.f.,

$$   D_{t=0}^n \; e^{-t^2} \; e^{-2xt} \;  D_{s=0}^m  \; e^{-s^2} \; e^{-2xs} \;  = \hat{H}_n(-2x) \; \hat{H}_m(-2x) $$

$$=   D_{t=0}^n  \;  D_{s=0}^m  \; e^{-(t^2+s^2)} \;e^{-2x(t+s)}  ,$$

so

$$  D_{t=0}^n  \;  D_{s=0}^m  \; e^{-(t^2+s^2)} \; \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \; e^{-x^2} \; e^{-2x(t+s)} \; dx = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \;  \hat{H}_n(-2x) \; \hat{H}_m(-2x) \; e^{-x^2} \; dx$$

$$ =  \; D_{t=0}^n  \;  D_{s=0}^m  \; \sqrt{\pi} \; e^{-(t^2+s^2) + (s+t)^2} = \; D_{t=0}^n  \;  D_{s=0}^m  \; \sqrt{\pi} \; e^{2st} = \sqrt{\pi} \; 2^n \; n! \; \delta_{n,m} , $$

or

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \;  \hat{H}_n(2x) \; \hat{H}_m(2x) \; e^{-x^2} \; dx = \sqrt{\pi} \; 2^n \; n! \; \delta_{n,m},$$

where $\delta_{n,m}$ is the Kronecker delta, which is unity for $n=m$ and vanishes otherwise.

**_____________________________________**

**E) A Gaussian integral transform of Hermite polynomials**

$$  D_{t=0}^n  \; e^{t^2} \; e^{xt}  = H_n(x)  $$

A Wick rotation gives

$$  \;(-i)^n D_{t=0}^n  \; e^{-t^2} \; e^{ixt}  = H_n(x)  .$$

Then

$$(-i)^n \; D_{t=0}^n  \; e^{-t^2} \; \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \; e^{-x^2} \; e^{ixt} \; dx = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \;  H_n(x) \; e^{-x^2} \; dx$$

$$ =(-i)^n \; D_{t=0}^n  \sqrt{\pi} \; e^{-(1+\frac{1}{4})t^2}  =  \sqrt{\pi} \; (-\frac{5}{4})^{\frac{n}{2}} \cos(\pi\frac{n}{2}) \frac{n!}{(\frac{n}{2})!},$$

and

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \;  H_n(x) \; e^{-x^2} \; dx = \sqrt{\pi} \; (-\frac{5}{4})^{\frac{n}{2}}\; \hat{h}_n  = \sqrt{\pi} \; (-\frac{5}{4})^{\frac{n}{2}} \; \hat{H}_n(0) .$$

**_____________________________________**

**F) Mellin transform of the Gaussian**, Mellin transform interpolation of the coefficients of the Gaussian

The Mellin transform of the Gaussian is central to many discussions in analytic number theory and modular forms, being related to the Jacobi theta functions (e.g., see this [MO-Q](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/58004/how-does-one-motivate-the-analytic-continuation-of-the-riemann-zeta-function/97401#97401)).

The modified Mellin transform can be read off from the coefficients of the e.g.f. of the Gaussian per Ramanujan's master formula as shown in [MO-Q1](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/379428/ramanujans-master-formula-a-proof-and-relation-to-umbral-calculus/379453#379453), [MO-Q2](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/353282/an-analytic-continuation-of-power-series-coefficients/379477#379477), and [MSE-Q](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3099031/applications-of-ramanujans-master-theorem/4026016#4026016)).

$\; \; \; \; \;g(t) = e^{-t^2} = e^{\hat{h}. t}= \sum_{n \ge 0} \cos(\frac{\pi n}{2}) \; \frac{n!}{(\frac{n}{2})!} \;  \frac{t^n}{n!}, $

$\; \; \; \; \;f(t) = g(-t) =  e^{-t^2} =  g(t)= e^{-\hat{h}. t},$

and, for $ Re(s) > 0$, the modified Mellin transform gives

$$\hat{h}_{-s} = (\hat{h}.)^{-s} = \int_0^{\infty} e^{-\hat{h}. t} \; \frac{t^{s-1}}{(s-1)!} \; dt$$

$$ =  \int_0^{\infty} e^{-t^2} \; \frac{t^{s-1}}{(s-1)!} \; dt   =  \cos(\pi\frac{ s}{2}) \; \frac{(-s)!}{(-\frac{s}{2})!} = \frac{1}{2}\frac{(\frac{s}{2}-1)!}{(s-1)!} .$$

The Mellin transform gives the general formula for the one-sided Gaussian integral transform of the monomials $x^n$ as

$$n! \; \hat{h}_{-n-1} = \int_0^{\infty} e^{-x^2} \; x^n \; dx = \frac{1}{2} \; (\frac{n-1}{2})! \; . $$

In particular for $s = 1$, or $n =0$,

$$ \hat{h}_{-1} = \int_0^{\infty} e^{-x^2} \;  dx   = \frac{1}{2}\; (-\frac{1}{2})! = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}.$$

For $n=1,3,5,7,9,...$, the sequence $n! \; \hat{h}_{-n-1}$ is $(\frac{1}{2}, \;\frac{1}{2}, \;1, \;3, \;12, \;60, ...)$ with the numerators OEIS [A001710](https://oeis.org/A001710).

For $n=0,2,4,6,..$, the sequence $n! \; \hat{h}_{-n-1}$ is $\sqrt{\pi} \cdot (\frac{1}{2}, \; \frac{1}{2^2}, \;\frac{3}{2^3}, \;\frac{15}{2^4}, \;\frac{105}{2^5}, ...)$, a sequence with the double factorials of OEIS  [A001147](https://oeis.org/A001147) (see also [A094638](https://oeis.org/A094638)) in the numerators.

Both OEIS entries have extensive references.

**_____________________________________**

**G) Cumulants**

The coefficients of the differential component of the raising op for an Appell sequence, determined from the natural log of the e.g.f. of the Appell moments, are proportional to the cumulants associated to the moment e.g.f. via the cumulant expansion formula of OEIS [A127671](https://oeis.org/A127671). In particular, the raising ops of the Hermite polynomial families are $R = x + D_{t=D_x} \ln[e^{-\alpha \; t^2}]  = x - \alpha \;  D_x$, where $\alpha$ is proportional to the variance, or second cumulant, of the Gaussian probability density function (pdf).

A characteristic function of the normalized Gaussian pdf with $t$ treated as a random variable is, from the two-sided LPT above,

$$<e^{ xt}> \;  = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-t^2}}{\sqrt{\pi}} \; e^{ xt} \; dt = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}} e^{\hat{H}.(x)t} \; dt = e^{\frac{x^2}{4}} = e^{\frac{h.}{2}x}  $$

with the moments given by

$$<t^n > \;  =  \; D_{x=0}^n \; <e^{xt}> \;  =  D_{x=0}^n e^{\frac{x^2}{4}} = \frac{h_n}{2^n} = \frac{H_n(0)}{2^n} =  |\cos(\frac{\pi n}{2})| \; \frac{n!}{(\frac{n}{2})!} \frac{1}{2^{n}},$$

agreeing with the Mellin transform result.

The formal cumulants in terms of formal moments (convergence of the e.g.f.s not required) are given by the cumulant expansion formula (see the associated partition polynomials in the Lang link in A127671)

$$\ln[<e^{xt}>] = \ln[\; e.g.f \; of \; moments \; ] = \; e.g.f. \; of \; cumulants, $$

and, in our case for the Gaussian, reduces to

$$  \ln[e^{\frac{x^2}{4}}] = \frac{1}{2} \frac{x^2}{2} = (<t^2> - <t>^2) \; \frac{x^2}{2}  = (<t-<t>>^2) \; \frac{x^2}{2}, $$

so the cumulants vanish except for the second cumulant, the variance, which is 1/2. The cumulant partition polynomials are invertible (a graded involution), so the formal cumulants completely define the formal moment e.g.f., and, if this is given by a characteristic function obtained by an invertible transform of a pdf, they define the pdf as well. See "[Three lectures on free probability](https://arxiv.org/abs/1205.2097)" by Novak and LaCroix for the significance of cumulants in combinatorics and statistics and for an elementary proof of the central limit theorem via cumulants. See also the stat mech refs in OEIS [A036040](https://oeis.org/A036040). See the [Wick's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wick%27s_theorem) and [Isserlis'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isserlis%27_theorem) theorems for generalizations.

**_____________________________________**

For more connections of the Gausssian, the Hermite polynomials, and the Graves-Lie-Heisenberg-Weyl group/algebra to other areas of math and physics, see "[On the role of the Heisenberg group in harmonic analysis](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.bams/1183547543)" by Roger Howe, "[Heisenberg groups, theta functions, and Weil representation](https://arxiv.org/abs/0905.1865)" by Yang, "[An Exercise(?) in Fourier Analysis on the Heisenberg Group](https://arxiv.org/abs/1502.04160)" by Bump, Diaconis, Hicks, and Widom, "[Theta and Riemann xi function representations from harmonic oscillator eigensolutions](https://arxiv.org/abs/math-ph/0612086)" by Coffey, and "[Quantum vs. classical integrability in Calogero-Moser systems](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0204039)" by Corrigan and Sasaki.

---

(Edit 5/14/21)

**Generalization: Gaussian functions, moments, and the Heisenberg-Weyl algebra**

Many important polynomial sequences $p_n(x)$ (in particular, all Sheffer polynomial sequences, related to invertible lower triangular matrices, including the Bernoulli and families of Laguerre and Hermite polynomials) have ladder ops--lowering and raising ops $L$ and $R$--such that

$ L \; p_n(x) = n \; p_{n-1}(x)$ and $R \; p_n(x) = p_{n+1}(x)$

with $L \; p_0(x) = 0.$

The commutator of the ops gives $[L,R] = 1$; i.e., $[L,R] \; p_n(x) = (LR -RL) \; p_n(x) = p_n(x).$

For operators that satisfy the commutator relations $[X,[X,Y]] = [Y,[Y,X]]= 0,$ the BCHD expansion reduces to

$$ e^{tX} e^{tY} = e^{t(X+Y) + \frac{t^2}{2}[X,Y]},$$

so the operator disentangling relationship

$$ e^{tR} e^{tL} = e^{t(R+L) + \frac{t^2}{2}[R,L]} = e^{\frac{-t^2}{2}} \; e^{t(R+L)}$$

holds, in which a Gaussian function appears.

For $p_0(x) =1$ with the umbral notation and maneuver $p.(x)^n = p_n(x)$,

$$ e^{tR} e^{tL}\; 1 =  e^{t R} \; 1= e^{t \; p.(x)} = e^{\frac{-t^2}{2}} \; e^{t(R+L)} \; 1  $$

so, with the moments $\bar{h}_n$ of the Gaussian function defined by  $e^{ \;\frac{t^2}{2}} = e^{\bar{h}.t}$,

$$e^{\frac{t^2}{2}} \; e^{t \; p.(x)} =  e^{t\; \bar{h}.} \; e^{t \; p.(x)} = e^{t\; (\bar{h}.+p.(x))} = e^{t \; \bar{H}.(p.(x))}  = e^{t(R+L)} \; 1,$$

with

$$\bar{H}_n(x) = (\bar{h}.+x)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n \; \binom{n}{k} \; \bar{h}_k \; x^{n-k},$$

and we can identify

$$(L+R)^n \; 1= (\bar{h}. + p.(x))^n = \bar{H}_n(p.(x));$$

that is,

$L+R$ is the raising op for the sequence $P_n(x) = \bar{H}_n(p.(x))$.

Since the lowering and raising ops for the monomial sequence $p_n(x) = x^n$ are $x$ and $D$, the raising op for the family of modified Hermite polynomials $\bar{H}.(x)$ above (OEIS [A099174](https://oeis.org/A099174)) is $x+D_x$, and the form of the polynomials gives $D_x$ as the lowering op. In the earlier answer above, you can see that diverse properties of the Gaussian function/distribution follow from this operator relation. Many can be generalized. For example, the raising op formula

$$(x+D) \; \bar{H}_n(x) = \bar{H}_{n+1}(x)$$

gives an instance

$$\bar{H}_{n+1}(x) = x  \; \bar{H}_n(x) - n \; \bar{H}_{n-1}(x)$$

of the general recurrence relation that is a sufficient and necessary condition for a sequence to be a set of orthonormal polynomials on the real line w.r.t. a weight function/distribution (see the discussion surrounding Favard's theorem in Operator Theory: A Comprehensive Course in Analysis, Part 4 by Barry Simon).

Another example is the evolution equation

$$ D_t \; f(x,t)  = (R+L) \; f(x,t),$$

which follows from the above exponential rep with the solution

$$f(x,t)  = e^{t \; P.(x)} = e^{t \; \bar{H}_n(p.(x))} = e^{t \; (\bar{h}.+p.(x))}$$

$$ =  e^{t \bar{h}.} \; e^{t \; p.(x)} = e^{ \frac{t^2}{2}} \; A(t) \; e^{x \; B(t)} , $$

an e.g.f for a Sheffer sequence, for which $A(t)$ and $B(t)$ are analytic about the origin and $A(0) =1$,  $B(0)=0$, and $B'(0) \neq 0$.

From the calculus of Appell Sheffer sequences, a solution of the deformed heat/diffusion equation

$$D_t \; \tilde{g}(x,t) = [ \; \frac{D_x^2}{2} + \sum_{n \geq 2}  \; c_n \; \frac{D_x^n}{n} \;] \; \tilde{g}(x,t) $$

is

$$\tilde{g}(x,t) = e^{t\frac{D_x^2}{2}} \; \exp[\; t \; \sum_{n \geq 2}  \; c_n \; \frac{D_x^n}{n} \;] \; g(x)$$

$$ =  g[ H.[S.(y,\gamma_2,\gamma_3,...)] \sqrt{t}] = g[ S.(H.(y),\gamma_2,\gamma_3,...) \sqrt{t}] =  g[ S.(x,t\bar{c}_2,tc_3,...)]$$

with

$ \gamma_n = \; t^{1-\frac{n}{2}} \; c_n$ for $n > 1$,

$y =x/ \sqrt{t} $,

$\bar{c}_2 = 1 + c_2$, and

$S_n(c_1,c_2,...,c_n) $ are the Stirling partition polynomials of the first kind (OEIS [A036039](https://oeis.org/A036039)), a.k.a. the cycle index polynomials of the symmetric groups, defined by

$e^{t \; S.(c_1,...)} =  \exp[-\ln(1-c.t)] = \exp[\sum_{k > 0} c_k \; \frac{t^k}{k}].$

Since these umbral compositions can be represented by multiplication of invertible lower triangular matrices, conjugations (or 'axes rotations') can be used to map between the nondeformed and deformed reps.

**_____________________________________**

Edit (5/30/21):

**A Combinatorial Perspective**

Underlying all of the relationships above is the fact $e^{t^2/2} = e^{\bar{h}. t}$ is the e.g.f. for the aerated odd double factorials ($\bar{h}_0=1,\;\bar{h}_1=0,\;\bar{h}_2=1,\;\bar{h}_3=0, \;\bar{h_4}=3,...$), which enumerate the number of perfect matchings of the n vertices of the regular (n-1)-dimensional simplices (hypertriangles, or hypertetrahedrons).

$(x+D_x)^{n}$ as a normal-ordered operator, i.e., expanded and expressed with all derivatives to the right of the variable $x$, has the same coefficients as the polynomial $\bar{H}_{n}(x+y) = (\bar{h}.+x+y)^{n}$ in the commutative variables $x$ and $y$ with the multinomial enumerating permutations of three families of objects--vertices labelled with either $x$ or $y$, or perfect (pair) matchings of the unlabeled vertices for the n vertices of the (n-1)-dimensional simplex. For example, $(x+D)^2 = xx +xD+Dx + D^2 = x^2 + 2xD + D^2+1$ corresponds to $H_n(x+y) = (h.+x+y)^2 = h_0 \dot (x+y)^2 + 2 h_1 \cdot (x+y) + h_2 =  x^2 +2xy +y^2+1$ which, in turn, corresponds to a line segment, the 1-D simplex, with both vertices labeled with $x$'s; or one with an $x$, the other a $y$; or both vertices labeled with $y$'s; or one unlabeled matched pair.

Comment: Also good to know: the Hermite functions give a Schauder basis for the Schwartz space $\mathscr{S}(\mathbb{R})$ and therefore, and more importantly, also for the space of tempered distributions $\mathscr{S}'(\mathbb{R})$. They essentially trivialize lots (but not all) of functional analytic questions about these spaces.

Comment: @AbdelmalekAbdesselam, refs? Connected to the use of the Gaussian as a nascent Dirac delta and the Cauchy problem, similar to Sato's theory of hyperfunctions?

Comment: Don't know about nascent delta. For the Schauder basis, I have some notes from a course I taught. Otherwise there is https://aip.scitation.org/doi/abs/10.1063/1.1665472?casa_token=1bzvxXVIVmoAAAAA:G-yo_ynSsroUN4LoUAZ7neVwNZrpcjvyXG52JzOjZV5ueB4DFOnlTG_Wuycfb3zPUucrtzKOqpYT but not well written, it's also in Reed Simon Vol 1, not better, most of the proof punted in the exercises. Simon's new book on analysis is much better.

Comment: BTW, Treves in his book on distributions does not mention this. Other authors credit Reed-Simon, but this was well known to Schwartz and Grothendieck (mentioned in Schwartz's book on distributions and A.G. in his thesis in Memoirs of AMS). I don't know who first discovered the result. Wiener?

Comment: @AbdelmalekAbdesselam, thanks.  Bet you can find the germ of the idea in the convolutional soln. to the Cauchy problem mentioned above as you can for the Schwartz distributions in 19th century classic potential theory as sketched in https://mathoverflow.net/questions/127601/does-the-derivative-of-log-have-a-dirac-delta-term/364456#364456. Sato runs with this. Would be interesting to find a good monograph comparing, contrasting the theories and elucidating the historical connections.

Comment: @AbdelmalekAbdesselam, link to your notes? I found "Hermite expansions of some tempered distributions" by Chihara et al., which refs Simon and also Kagawa. Expansion of tempered distributions works as well for the Laguerre polynomials (see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/382735/whats-the-matrix-of-logarithm-of-derivative-operator-ln-d-what-is-the-rol/383563#383563) and should also for similar orthogonal polynomial sequences.

Comment: In another MO-Q Nik Weaver alludes to "Quantum Mechanics in Rigged Hilbert Space Language" by Rafael de la Madrid Modino--a good intro to the Hermite polynomials and the quantum harmonic oscillator and various spaces associated with them.

Comment: On relation to the Heisenberg uncertainty relation, see this Oxford lecture https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=cz0-HcAtU5U

Comment: See also "Adelic harmonic oscillator" by Branko Dragovicha https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0404160

Comment: Some researchers are exploring extended Heisenberg algebras and categories, such as Khovanov in "Heisenberg algebra and a graphical calculus" (https://arxiv.org/abs/1009.3295) and Brunden, Savage, and Webster  (https://arxiv.org/abs/2007.01642).  For more Hermite integrals and uniqueness of the Hermite polynomials as the only orthogonal Appell family, see Anshelevich  http://see-math.math.tamu.edu/~manshel/papers/Hermite-integrals.pdf.

Comment: See also the Gauss-Weierstrass operator/transform https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_transform

Comment: Related: Gauss-Markov theorem.

Comment: See also "On Riemann's zeta function" by Bump and Ng (https://eudml.org/doc/173728) and the closely related "Binomial Polynomials Mimicking Riemann’s Zeta Function" by Coffey and Lettington (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1703.09251.pdf).

Comment: For a discussion of integral transforms with general quadratic equations in an exponential, see "On self-reciprocal functions under a class of integral transforms" by Kurt Bernardo Wolf.

Comment: For more on the heat/diffusion equation, small oscillations, and quadratic relations, see Arnold's "Lectures on Partial Differential Equations."

Comment: More on the associations among the Heisenberg-Weyl algebra, matchings on simplices, and Gaussian distributions soon to come at https://oeis.org/A344678.

Comment: "Gaussian processes and Feynman diagrams" by
William G. Faris, related to the general $Z = e^F$ (OEIX A036040) enumerating number of disconnected objects formed from connected ones, in this case a single graph with one edge with the exponential generating function $F = x^2/2$. The cumulant expansion formula A127671 (cf. A263634 for relation to the raising op for Appell polynomials) gives the inverse relation--connected from disconnected--mentioned in the answer.

Comment: Ghys and Ranicki, in "Signatures in algebra, topology and dynamics", use the expression 'quadratic form' 51 times whereas 'Gaussian' is used only once in 'Gaussian elimination'. Functions, $f(z)$, are extremely important, of course, in mathematics also, but that doesn't explain the interpretation and utility of $e^{f(z)}$.

Comment: @TomCopeland : If you just google "latex symbols" you can see at once how to write $$\langle t-\langle t\rangle\rangle^2 $$ instead of $$<t-<t>>^2. $$

Comment: @MichaelHardy, I've done that for more important equations in other writings. Feel free to edit to your tastes as long as it doesn't change the content.  I think I've invested quite a lot of time and effort on specifics in this answer to be forgiven for not going the whole ten yards on the formatting (28 taps vs. 4), and other unfinished  notes beckon.

Comment: On matched pairings, the Gaussian, and the CLT: Terence Tao's central limit theorem, Double Factorials (!!) and the Moment Method (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oPQ4mNcqY7k&t=665s) by Nica.