# What makes Gaussian distributions special? Local field version?

Tags: nt.number-theory, pr.probability, fourier-analysis

This question is inspired by the recent one about Gaussian measures over the reals:

[What makes Gaussian distributions special?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/382855/what-makes-gaussian-distributions-special)

I would be interested in a similar list of characterizations for the probability measure, on the field of $p$-adic numbers $\mathbb{Q}_p$, whose density with respect to the standard additive Haar measure is given by the indicator function of the ring of $p$-adic integers $\mathbb{Z}_p$.

Comment: Probably worth linking to this paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9803046

Comment: Thanks! If you have time it would be good if you could extract one of the characterizations in the paper and post that as an answer.

Comment: Have you checked the refs in https://mathoverflow.net/questions/339214/applications-of-number-theory-in-dynamical-systems/339226#339226 ?

Comment: Another question:  is an appropriate $p$-adic analogue of the Gaussian still real-valued, or should one look for a $p$-adic-valued analogue?

Comment: I would say that it ought to be $\Bbb{C}$-valued owing to comments in my post below.

Comment: @InesInstitoris, it's actually your post (which I enjoyed—thank you!) that made me think of it.  Your post comes from the same point of view as my training, the complex represetation theory of finite and $p$-adic groups; but there is also a rich (if newer) theory of $p$-adic represetations of $p$-adic groups, and one might look there to find an appropriate description of $p$-adic valued special functions.  (I don't know if that community already has such a theory, or even if they have a Weil representation.)

Comment: @LSpice: I know that there are very interesting things going on when looking a p-adic valued stuff (e.g., yesterday's article by Fargues and Scholze which looks quite exciting to me). However, I would like this question to stay within the realm of Archimedian-valued things. What you said though could be the premise of another MO question which I think would be quite nice. I already took inspiration from an MO question to write this one. You could do the same with my question.

Comment: This question reminds me of [Sally and Taibleson - Special functions on local fields](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02392818).

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps one answer is the appearance of the Gaussian in the
*oscillator* (a.k.a. *Weil*) representation --- which makes sense
even in non-zero characteristic. You're probably
aware of the construction of this infinite dimensional representation
for the double cover of $\mathrm{SL}_2(\Bbb{R})$. The story for $\mathrm{SL}_2 \big( \Bbb{F}_q \big)$
where $q$ a power of a prime strongly parallels the continuous story
except, of course, it's finite:

Choose any non-square $\delta \in \Bbb{F}_q$ and form the quadratic extension
$\Bbb{F}_q(\delta) \cong \Bbb{F}_q^2$. As usual, we identify elements of
$\Bbb{F}_q(\delta)$ as linear combinations $z = a + \sqrt{\delta} b$
with $a, b \in \Bbb{F}_q$ subject the usual formulae for addition
and multiplication; *conjugation* and *norm* are expressed as
$\bar{z} = a - \sqrt{\delta} b$ and $\mathrm{N}(z) = a^2 - \delta b^2$
respectively. We'll need to choose (any) non-trivial additive
character $\psi: \Bbb{F}_q \longrightarrow \Bbb{C}^*$ together with
any multiplicative character
$\chi: \Bbb{F}_q(\delta)^* \longrightarrow \Bbb{C}^*$ which generates the
character group of $\Bbb{F}_q(\delta)^*$. Morally $\psi$ plays the
role of the exponential function $\exp: \Bbb{R} \longrightarrow \Bbb{R}^*$
in this finite context. Now set

\begin{equation}
W_\chi := \ \left\{ 
\begin{array}{l}
\displaystyle \text{all functions} \
f: \Bbb{F}_q(\delta) \longrightarrow \Bbb{C} \ \ \text{such that} \\
\displaystyle
f(wz) = \overline{\chi(w)} \, f(z) \ \text{whenever $\mathrm{N}(w)=1$}
\end{array} \right\}
\end{equation}

which is $q-1$ dimensional. The *oscillator* representation $\varrho_\chi: \mathrm{SL}_2(\Bbb{F}_q) 
\longrightarrow \mathrm{GL}(W_\chi)$ is determined by the action of the
follow elements, which generate $\mathrm{SL}_2(\Bbb{F}_q)$:

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{ll}
\displaystyle \varrho_\chi { \scriptstyle \begin{pmatrix} x & 0 \\ 0 & x^{-1} \end{pmatrix}}
f(z) 
&\displaystyle = \
f(xz) \\
\displaystyle \displaystyle \varrho_\chi { \scriptstyle \begin{pmatrix} 1 & \ \ y \\ 0 & \ \ 1 \end{pmatrix}} f(z)  
&\displaystyle = \ \underbrace{\psi \big( y \, \mathrm{N}(z) \big)}_{\text{the Gaussian $G_y(z)$}} \cdot f(z) \\
\displaystyle \displaystyle \varrho_\chi { \scriptstyle \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}} f(z) 
&\displaystyle = \ -q \widehat{f}(-\bar{z})
\end{array}
\end{equation}

where $\widehat{f}$ is the Fourier transform of $f$ with respect to the
additive structure of $\Bbb{F}_q(\sqrt{\delta})$. Like the continuous Gaussian,
$G_y(z)$ is an eigenfunction of this Fourier transform.

As far as I know, the construction that I've outlined (and which I learned from Amritanshu Prasad's online notes) can be carried out for
$\mathrm{SL}_2\big( \Bbb{Z}/q\Bbb{Z} \big)$ where $q= p^N$ is still a power of a fixed prime $p$. Furthermore a coherent choice of additive and multiplicative characters
$\psi_N$ and $\chi_N$ can be made for each $N \geq 1$ so that these oscillator representations agree with the inverse system

\begin{equation}
1 \longleftarrow \Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb{Z} \stackrel{\ \text{mod $p$}}{\longleftarrow} \Bbb{Z}/p^2\Bbb{Z} \stackrel{\ \text{mod $p^2$}}{\longleftarrow}
\Bbb{Z}/p^3\Bbb{Z} \longleftarrow \, \cdots
\end{equation}

thus allowing the oscillator representations $\varrho_{\chi_N}$ to be exported to the $p$-adic integers $\Bbb{Z}_p$, which will inherent some kind of Gaussian-like function $\varprojlim G_{\bf y}$ where
${\bf y}= (y_1,y_2,y_3, \dots)$ and $y_N = y_{N+1} \, \text{mod $p^N$}$
for each $N \geq 1$.

Comment: I would follow this up with the observation that Young's convolution inequality $\| f * g\|_r \leq c_{p,q} \| f \|_p \, \| g \|_q$ with ${1 \over p} + {1 \over q} = 1 + {1 \over r}$ is maximized when $f$ and $g$ are Gaussians. One might ask whether or not the same characterization holds for the $\Bbb{F}_q$-Gaussians $G_y$.

Comment: In a similar vein, the Babenko-Beckner inequality $\| \widehat{f} \|_q \leq \tilde{c}_{p,q} \| f \|_p$ with ${1 \over p} + {1 \over q} = 1$ and $1 < p \leq q$ is maximized by Gaussians. Does this characterize $\Bbb{F}_q$-Gaussians ? Is there some analogue at least ?

Comment: Thank you for a very nice answer! I remember reading a long time ago about Segal-Shale-Weil and the metaplectic representation, Mehler's formula etc. Do you know if one gets the Fourier transform as a particular value of the corresponding unitary representation, like at $t=\frac{\pi}{4}$ if I remember correctly for the Oscillator? If so are the eigenfunctions determined, like Hermite functions in the Archimedean case?

Comment: I also hope someone will write an answer along the line of your comments, namely some charaterization of the indicator function of $\mathbb{Z}_p$ as some kind of maximizer/minimizer.

Comment: If $\delta = -1$ is a non-square in $\Bbb{F}_q$ then the Fourier transform is indeed a special value of the action the subgroup $\mathrm{SO}_2(\Bbb{F}_q)$ consisting of all $2 \times 2$ matrices of the form $\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ \delta b & a \end{pmatrix}$ with $a^2- \delta b^2 =1$. As far as Hermite functions are concerned, wouldn't you need a good candidate for a laplace operator $\Delta: \Bbb{C} \big[\Bbb{F}_q (\sqrt{ \delta }) \big] \longrightarrow \Bbb{C} \big[\Bbb{F}_q (\sqrt{ \delta }) \big]$ as well as an appropriate $\Bbb{C}$-valued potential function to play the role of $|z|^2$ ?

Comment: Actually there is already a candidate for $\Delta$. The action of the associated heat-propagator $\exp(- t\Delta)$ on $\Bbb{C} \big[ \Bbb{F}_q (\sqrt{\delta}) \big]$ should be implemented by convolution with the $\Bbb{F}_q$-Gaussian, which is how the operator $\varrho_\chi \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ t & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ acts on functions $f \in \Bbb{C} \big[ \Bbb{F}_q (\sqrt{\delta}) \big]$.

Comment: ... or more simply put: The potential function ought to be something like $v(z) := \log G_{\, \! 1}(z)$ while the Laplacian $\Delta$ should be defined by $\Delta f (z) := \sum_{w \in  \Bbb{F}_q( \sqrt{\delta})} \, \widehat{v}(z-w) f(w)$ for functions $f \in \Bbb{C}\big[ \Bbb{F}_q( \sqrt{\delta}) \big]$. Now we can try to identify Hermite functions by fishing for eigenfunctions of the $f \mapsto \Delta f - vf$ operator.

Comment: I don't know if trying to mimic the real case too closely is good, namely, defining $H$ as some schrodinger operator before taking $e^{-tH}$ with $t$ real. I think time is p-adic here. Rather I would look for simultaneous eigenfunctions for the representation operators $U(M)$ where the $M$'s are some of your $2\times 2$ matrices.