# Finding (and saturating) a sharp Babenko-Beckner inequality for finite fields

Tags: nt.number-theory, gr.group-theory, harmonic-analysis, finite-fields, fourier-transform

My question is a follow-up to Abdelmalek Abdesselam's recent post

[What makes Gaussian distributions special? Local field version?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/382952/what-makes-gaussian-distributions-special-local-field-version/385411?noredirect=1#comment982188_385411)

asking about various characterizations of (real-valued) Gaussian distributions which remain valid for other analogues of Gaussian distributions/functions (e.g. in the p-adic context). One interesting
characterization arises with Babenko-Beckner's refinement of the Hausdorff inequality (see [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babenko–Beckner_inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babenko%E2%80%93Beckner_inequality)). For real numbers $s, t$ with ${1 \over s} + {1 \over t} = 1$ and $1 < s \leq 2$ it is known that
the Fourier transform $f \mapsto \hat{f}$ maps $L^s(\Bbb{R}^n)$
to $L^t(\Bbb{R}^n)$ and satisfies the inequality

\begin{equation} \displaystyle
\| \hat{f} \, \|_t \ \leq \ s^{n \over {2s}} \, t^{-{n \over {2t}}}  \, \| f \|_s \quad 
\left( {\scriptstyle \begin{array}{l} \text{Babenko}
\\ \text{Beckner} \\ \text{inequality} \end{array}} \right)
\end{equation}

When $s = t = 2$ this inequality becomes an equality which is
valid for all $f \in L^2(\Bbb{R}^n)$. For $s < 2$ equality
is achieved if and only if $f$ is a Gaussian function. If the factor
$s^{n \over {2s}} \, t^{-{n \over {2t}}} $
is omitted the inequality is still valid although it ceases to
be sharp; this formulation is known as the Hausdorff-Young
inequality.

My question concerns, initially, an analogue of the Hausdorff-Young
inequality for (quadratic extensions of) finite fields:
Let $q$ be a power of a prime $p$
and let $\Bbb{F}_q$ be the finite field with $q$ elements.
Choose a non-square $\delta \in \Bbb{F}_q$ and form the
quadratic extension $\Bbb{F}_q\big( \sqrt{\delta} \big)$.
We view elements of $\Bbb{F}_q\big( \sqrt{\delta} \big)$
as linear combinations of the form $z = x + \sqrt{\delta} y$
with $x, y \in \Bbb{F}_q$ subject to the usual rules of
addition and multiplication. Conjugation and norm are
expressed, respectively, as $\bar{z} := z^q = x - \sqrt{\delta} y$
and $\mathrm{N}(z) := z\bar{z} = x^2 - \delta y^2$. Furthermore
define $\mathrm{Tr}(z) := z + \bar{z}$. Choose any non-trivial
additive character $\psi: \Bbb{F}_q \longrightarrow \Bbb{C}^*$
and define the $\Bbb{F}_q\big( \sqrt{\delta} \big)$-Fourier transform
$\widehat{f}$ of a complex-valued function $f: \Bbb{F}_q\big( \sqrt{\delta} \big) \longrightarrow \Bbb{C}$ by

\begin{equation}
\widehat{f}(z) \ := \
{1 \over q} \, \sum_{w \in \Bbb{F}_q\big( \sqrt{\delta} \big)} \,
f(w) \, \psi \Big(-\mathrm{Tr}(zw) \Big)
\end{equation}

If we endow the function space $\Bbb{C}\big[ \Bbb{F}_q\big( \sqrt{\delta} \big) \big]$ with the hermitian inner product

\begin{equation}
\langle f , g \rangle \ := \  \sum_{w \in \Bbb{F}_q\big( \sqrt{\delta} \big)} \,
f(w) \, \overline{g(w)} \end{equation}

then Plancherel holds, i.e. $\| \widehat{f} \, \|_2 =  \| f \|_2$ and the Hausdorff-Young inequality takes the form

\begin{equation} (\dagger)
\quad \| \widehat{f} \, \|_t \ \leq \ \|f \, \|_s
\end{equation}

for any pair of real numbers $s,t$ with ${1 \over s} + {1 \over t} = 1$ and $1 < s \leq 2$. This is a finite field adaptation of a more general version of the Hausdorff-Young inequality that holds for
finite abelian groups (see for example https://www.e-periodica.ch/cntmng?pid=ens-001:2000:46::190).

**Question 1:** Is inequality ($\dagger$) sharp
for values $1<s<2$? If it is, which functions saturate
the inequality?

I'm inclined to the view that $(\dagger)$ is not sharp.
Consider functions of the form

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{ll}
\displaystyle \mathrm{G}_x(z) 
&\displaystyle := \ \psi \big( x\, \mathrm{N}(z) \big) \\
\displaystyle \mathrm{H}_v(z) 
&\displaystyle := \ \psi \big( \mathrm{Tr} \, (vz)^2  \big)
\end{array}
\end{equation}

where $x \in \Bbb{F}_q$ and $v \in \Bbb{F}_q\big( \sqrt{\delta}\big)$ are parameters. I would argue that $\mathrm{G}_x$ should be regarded as $\Bbb{F}_q\big( \sqrt{\delta} \big)$ analogue of the real-valued Gaussian
$z \mapsto \exp ( -x |z|^2)$ on the complex plane
for reasons connected to the cuspidal representation theory
of $\mathrm{SL}_2\big( \Bbb{F}_q \big)$ which are briefly
outlined in my response to Abdesselam's post. Both $\mathrm{G}_x$
and $\mathrm{H}_v$ are **near** eigenfunctions of the $\Bbb{F}_q\big( \sqrt{\delta} \big)$-Fourier transform. Let's check this to be sure:

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{ll}
\displaystyle \widehat{\mathrm{G}}_x(z) 
&\displaystyle = \ {1 \over q} 
\sum_{w \in \Bbb{F}_q\big( \sqrt{\delta} \big)}
\psi \big(x \mathrm{N}(w) \big) \, \psi \big(-\mathrm{Tr}(zw) \big) \\
&\displaystyle = \  {1 \over q} 
\sum_{w \in \Bbb{F}_q\big( \sqrt{\delta} \big)}
\psi \big(x w \bar{w} - zw - \bar{z} \bar{w} \big) \\
&\displaystyle = \  {1 \over q} 
\sum_{w \in \Bbb{F}_q\big( \sqrt{\delta} \big)}
\psi \Big( x^{-1} \mathrm{N}\big( xw - \bar{z} \big) - x^{-1} \mathrm{N}(z) \Big) \\
&\displaystyle = \  {1 \over q} \ 
\psi \big(  -x^{-1} \mathrm{N}(z) \big) 
\sum_{w \in \Bbb{F}_q\big( \sqrt{\delta} \big)}
\psi \Big( x^{-1} \mathrm{N}\big( xw - \bar{z} \big) \Big) \\
&\displaystyle = \  {1 \over q} \ 
\mathrm{G}_{-x^{-1}}(z) 
\sum_{u \in \Bbb{F}_q\big( \sqrt{\delta} \big)}
\psi \big( x^{-1} \mathrm{N}(u) \big) \\
&\displaystyle = \  {1 \over q} \ 
\mathrm{G}_{-x^{-1}}(z)\,
\Bigg( 1 \, + \,  
(q+1) \, \sum_{y \in \Bbb{F}_q^*}
\psi \big( x^{-1} y \big) \Bigg) \\
&\displaystyle = \  {1 \over q} \ 
\mathrm{G}_{-x^{-1}}(z) \, \big( -q \big)
\quad \text{($\psi$ is non-trivial!)} \\
&\displaystyle = \ -\mathrm{G}_{-x^{-1}}(z) 
\end{array}
\end{equation}

Indeed, $\mathrm{G}_x$ will be an eigenfunction of the $\Bbb{F}_q\big( \sqrt{\delta} \big)$-Fourier transform if and only if $x^2 = -1$ in
$\Bbb{F}_q$. A similar computation confirms that

\begin{equation}
\widehat{\mathrm{H}}_v \ = \ \widehat{\mathrm{H}}_v(0) \, 
\overline{\mathrm{H}}_{(2v)^{-1}}
\end{equation}

where $\widehat{\mathrm{H}}_v(0)$ is a (normalized) Gauss sum
with unit complex modulus. Clearly $\mathrm{H}_v$ will be
a eigenfunction if and only if $v^4 = -{1 \over 4}$ in $\Bbb{F}_q \big( \sqrt{\delta} \big)$.

Note that $\| \mathrm{G}_x \|_s = \| \mathrm{H}_v \|_s = q^{2 \over s}$.

**Question 2:** Is the inequality

\begin{equation} (\dagger \dagger) 
\quad \displaystyle \| \widehat{f}  \|_t \ 
\leq \ q^{{2 \over t} - {2 \over s}} \, \| f \|_s 
\end{equation}

valid within the range $1 < s <2$? Is it sharp and which functions
saturate the inequality if it is? Clearly these would include functions of the form $f(z) = c \, \mathrm{G}_x(z-w)$
or $f(z) = c \, \mathrm{H}_v(z-w)$
for some choice of parameters $x \in \Bbb{F}_q$
or $v \in \Bbb{F}_q\big( \sqrt{\delta}\big)$, some shift $w \in \Bbb{F}_q\big( \sqrt{\delta} \big)$, and some overall scaling factor $c \in \Bbb{C}$. But are there others?

thanks, ines.

Comment: While editing questions is sometimes necessary, a large number of edits in a short space of time is frowned upon. Each edit bumps your question to the top of the stack, at the expense of other questions that their authors want looked at (which may be bumped off the front page). Please be aware of this, and take care to make combine multiple fixes into a single edit, and avoid trivial edits.